# Question on separable metric spaces and how to do them

Tags: advice

I have seen some questions and seen some idea. I am new to this topic 
and still find it confusing. I am kind of looking for a “algorithm “ to do them. I am using Sets & Metric spaces by Kaplansky  Section 5.2 pgs 94-96,1977 printing

My understanding in order to prove them

1. If (M,d) is a metric space. To show its separable ,show it has
    a countable dense subset
2. Show some how that an open base exists for the given case.

Reading back in the book as to dense subset, ”...If A is dense in B then there exists a sequence $(x_i)$ -> x ”, Theorem 52,pg 89 I know it is talking about isometry.. It is the dense subset part that I am interested in

Looking at Theorem 58 I think I can do the easier ones, if I
  mimic Kaplansky’s proof style.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: A technique  for doing them.